# ES6/ES7 extend class with same name

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, extends

Since conditional importing of modules is not yet implemented, how can I extend or override the same class:

```js
// I have a main class
// main.js
export default class Main {}

// Main class is used by myClass
class myClass {
  constructor(){
    new Main()
  }
}

// I have an extended main class
// main-extended.js
export default class MainExtended extends Main {}

// the MainExtended is now used by myClass
export class myClass {
  constructor(){
    new MainExtended()
  }
}


// third-class.js
// now I need to do this with any class I can find, 
// preferably with the extended version of both, if both defined
export default class ThirdClass {
  constructor(...args){
    return new myClass(...args)    
  }
}


// destinations

// index.js
import Main, {myClass} from main.js
import ThirdClass from third-class.js


// index-extended.js
import MainExtended, {myClass} from main-extended.js
import ThirdClass from third-class.js
```

The problem was that, for some reason, `index.js` compiled also included `myClass` calling for `MainExtended`, so I decided to only include `ThirdClass` in `index-extended`, as a bonus feature of `MainExtended`.

But I still want to know if there is another way around.

Comment: Why do you need to override a class with a child class of the same name? Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Because I have 2 separate destinations for these 2 functions that need to have same name. Let me update the question with some info, I seem to have to explain stuff.

Comment: Sorry, your updated code sheds no further light on what you actually want. If anything, I'm more confused than before.

Comment: `Because I have 2 separate destinations for these 2 functions that need to have same name`. Do you want to create an interface that accepts multiple types of subclasses? Please post your actual problem to provide context on why you need to have two classes with the same name; almost certainly, there is a better solution.

Comment: @ggorlen updated question, please have a look. I think you're up to something.

Comment: OK, this now makes more sense. It's the age old composition versus inheritance example, in fact. Just import `Main` or `MainExtended` (or any subclass) and pass the reference to `MyClass` constructor which instantiates it.

Comment: OK, I got some rest, put myself together, I updated the question to what I really have in mind, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like VLAZ said in the comments, I'm not 100% sure on what you're asking, but could you do something like this?

**Solution 1**

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(_main){
    myMain = _main;
  }
}

const regularMain = new MyClass(new Main());
const extendedMain = new MyClass(new MainExtended());
```

Comment: A flag argument is a code smell under normal circumstances but this is a constructor so it seems even worse than just passing a flag argument to a method. How is this going to scale if you add `class MainMoreExtended extends MainExtended`?

Comment: Yeah, that's fair... I'm mostly trying to figure out what the actual problem is here.

Comment: Me too and I'm really not understanding it. Perhaps OP is looking for dependency injection where they import, say a `SomeClass` type but at runtime what is delivered is a subclass of it. But it's really hard to say.

Comment: With the final update to the question, the update to the answer seems like what OP is looking for.